# view hierarchy error - trying to open up a new view controller in a new storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm getting viewheirarchy error - trying to open up a new view controller in a new storyboard.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {  
       super.viewDidLoad()

       if type == .Products {             
            self.presentViewController( UIStoryboard(name: "Fold", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainTableViewController") as! UITableViewController, animated: true, comp
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create a private var

```
private var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Fold", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
```

Create a func

```
func showYourViewController() throws -> UINavigationController {
    if let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? UINavigationController {
      if let mainTableViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? MainTableViewController {
        mainTableViewController.delegate = self
      } else {
        throw StoryboardError.InvalidCast
      }
      return navigationController
    } else {
      throw StoryboardError.InvalidCast
    }
}
```

Now you can use it

```
override func viewDidLoad() {  
   super.viewDidLoad()

   if type == .Products {             
    do {
        let yourViewController = try showYourViewController()
        setRootViewController(yourViewController)
    } catch StoryboardError.InvalidCast {
        print("Your View Controller was not of the expected type")
    } catch _ {
        print("Some other error occurred...")
    }
   }
 }
```

This is the StoryboardError enum

```
enum StoryboardError: ErrorType {
    case InvalidCast
}
```